# How to remove Nginx and compile new Nginx from source

Tags: nginx, installation

I've installed Nginx using `apt-get install nginx` but now I need to add SPDY and PageSpeed extensions. This is why I need to remove the current Nginx installation and install the new one from source.

How should I proceed? Do I have to uninstall the current Nginx and then compile the new one to avoid complications between those two?

How do I register the custom Nginx as a service so I can use `service nginx start` and make it start on boot?

Answer (score 1):

To create the **service nginx start**

1. Create a nginx entry in **/etc/init.d/** 
   `touch /etc/init.d/nginx`
2. Place your nginx service configuration in /etc/init.d/nginx Example configuration https://gist.github.com/j0hnb/37416fe362e20c82c295
3. Enable execute rights
   `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx`

That should allow you to run **Service nginx start**
Other service options

start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|configtest

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the existing nginx
Try the following commands
 (assuming that you are root)

```
apt-get autoremove nginx*
apt-get purge nginx*
```

And that should do the trick.
For compiling from the source, just grab the source from
http://nginx.org/en/download.html
For services, I would recommend on using

```
nginx
```

instead of

```
service nginx start
```

and

```
nginx -s stop
```

for

```
service nginx stop
```

. It is more convenient compared to the "traditional" mode.

Comment: You aren't answering the question of registering the nginx build as a system service

Comment: It is answered by others. I'm answering regarding the title and suggest an alternative command on having the service started.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should find [this article](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/08/21/use-nginx-spdy-without-compiling-nginx-and-without-a-recent-openssl/) quite useful.

For further references, you can just run `apt-get remove <package>` or `aptitude remove <package>` to uninstall any package but it won't hurt to look for leftovers on the usual places - namely `/etc/` - given that you edit those files and apt/aptitude may be reluctant to remove -- unless you specify the proper flags.

Remember, Google is your friend.